# how to reading multiple csv files from different paths in spark sql

Tags: python, sql, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

i'm trying to read multiple csv files in different folders

```
from pyspark.sql import *




spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("example") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option") \
    .getOrCreate()


folders = List("../../work/datainfo2/*.csv", "../../work/202003F1/*.csv")
df = spark.read.option("header", "false").csv(folders: _.csv)



df.createOrReplaceTempView("iris")
result = spark.sql("select * from iris where _c1 =1 order by _c0 desc")
result.show()
```

it throws an error

```
df = spark.read.option("header", "false").csv(folders: _.csv)
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've seen similar workarounds here but no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using scala syntax instead of python syntax.

This should work for you:

```
folders = ["../../work/datainfo2/*.csv", "../../work/202003F1/*.csv"]
df = spark.read.option("header", "false").csv(folders)
```